# Removing an element from Magento menu

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to remove this terrible "BUY THEME" link on our website: https://www.minxny.com

In case you're concerned, yes we legally purchased this theme through a 3rd party contractor who is no longer working with us. I'm in the process of retrieving the license from him (I don't even know where to put it in Magento). I want to get rid of the link today if possible.

I'm guessing I'd have to change a php files somewhere but I don't even know where to begin looking.

Comment: Can't you just ask the seller to help you?

Comment: I already sent out an email and I'm still waiting to here back from them.

Comment: Tried to use this directory? app/design/frontend/Magento

Comment: app/design/frontend/alomilano

Im guessing the name is of the theme is alomilano. I'm trying to go through every file but it has 10 sub themes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable or Delete here: Magiccart > Magic Menu > Manage Menu

Answer (score 0):

Add in CSS.

```
.level0.ext.first {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.